# Hosting a long-running console application on Windows?

Tags: iis, .net-core

I want to have a .NET Core console application that always runs. If it ever crashes, it should be restarted. The server it will run on has IIS installed, but I don't know if .NET Core supports attaching console apps to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need IIS for console app. What you are looking for is a Windows Service.
 Look on this [Running as Windows service](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1386) issue on github for details how you can achieve this.

[TopShelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) is also working on .NET Core support. You can monitor current progress [here](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/277).